# Canvas fillText not rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas

Please see my jsfiddle about this issue

https://jsfiddle.net/gL4m2z6v/

This is a fraction calculator in canvas that is supposed to show the greatest common factor between two fractions. You will need to expand the viewport in the fiddle and re run to see properly.

Relevant Code Excerpt - See fiddle for full

```
labelGCF: function(a, b){
    var b = a % b;
    if (b != 0) {
        console.log(a, window.innerWidth*0.8, winH50, textObj.fontSize);
        ctx.fillText(a, window.innerWidth*0.8, winH50, textObj.fontSize);
    } else {
        tableObj.labelGCF(b, a % b);
    }
}

// Exec
(function loop(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    // Draw Canvas Background
    c.width = canWidth;
    c.height = canHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canWidth,canHeight);
    // Draw Arrows
    arrowObj.draw(arrowObj[0]);
    arrowObj.draw(arrowObj[1]);
    arrowObj.draw(arrowObj[2]);
    arrowObj.draw(arrowObj[3]);
    coordsObj.arrows = 
    [arrowObj.getCoords(arrowObj[0]), arrowObj.getCoords(arrowObj[1]), arrowObj.getCoords(arrowObj[2]), arrowObj.getCoords(arrowObj[3])];
    // console.log("coordsObj.arrows: "+coordsObj.arrows);
    // Draw Table
    tableObj.draw();
    tableObj.labelXAxis();
    tableObj.labelYAxis();
    tableObj.labelTable();
    tableObj.drawGrid();
    tableObj.labelGCF(tableObj.xCount, tableObj.yCount);

})();
```

This code appears to excecute and the variables are consoled out correctly. I don;t know why the fillText doesnt work.

Comment: What is the output of console.log before ctx.fillText?

Comment: Look at this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text) and correct your arguments. "0" will be drawn on position (1536, 489.5)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't appear for me. Have you tried the fiddle or dl the code and used at full screen. It doesn't draw 0 on screen even if coords are inside viewport.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe it. I ended up playing with the coords and realized that the fillText was white. I use black in damn near 90% of the code. Hours gone. Ah the joys of programming. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, make sure your `fillText` coordinates are inside the canvas. An x of 1536 might be rightward off the canvas. Ditto with a y of 489.5.

**Second**, the last argument to `fillText` is the maximum width that canvas will use to display your text. Any text that doesn't fit in that width will be truncated. You're specifying `textObj.fontSize` (==48) which doesn't seem to relate to maximum width. So you might want to leave that argument out.

**And** ... if desired, you can center your text horizontally and vertically over your specified x,y using `textAlign` and `textBaseline`:

```
// center text horizontally at [x,y]
ctx.textAlign='center';

// center text vertically at [x,y]
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

// draw your text (it will be centered at the specified x,y)
ctx.fillText('Centered Text', x,y );
```

Comment: Hi markE, I run 1920x1080 so the text should appear inside the viewport. I am curious about the maxiumuim width ie second in your response... I thought this was pixels like 48px font size i.e. 48px wide. I use this same code for my other text which renders so I am still stumped.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione. Well, it is definitely the argument that limits displaying to 48 pixels in width. If you always have 1 character then all is good, but wider text will be cut off.

Comment: Yeah turned out fill text was set to white when i thought it was black and I couldnt see the text against the white background. lol :/